# batch file - make the batch file only runnable and not modifiable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, cmd

i have written a batch file , i want this batch file to run only and if some one wants to modify it he/she should enter in a password that i would give the person

is it possible?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It is a well known fact that if someone really wants to decompile your program, then they will find a way to do it, so you can't really protect against this with a fool proof solution.

However, you could use a [bat to exe converter](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e) and give the person a copy of the exe version to use, which you prompt for a password in.

Then, if they enter the correct password you could (if it's not that big) write the batch file contents into a text file for them to edit.

They would then need to convert this again into an exe (and they would also be able to change the password in the script).

This is obviously a messy way of doing it, but I can't think of any alternatives when your working with a batch file.

Comment: Just to add a note, the bat to exe converter will expose your batch script code at runtime, because it creates a temporary file of the batch script in the user's temp folder.  Any power user will be able to see the code.  All these tools do is add a layer of obfuscation between the user and the code which will only slow down slightly, those who want to edit it.  You could add layer upon layer of obfuscation, but that adds a lot of complexity, additional dependencies, and will hurt performance.  Answer first, Why must you hide your batch code from those, who you want to use it?